# Where is the "Hello World" coming from in Spring MVC Samples

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to review the code in Spring Show Case from git

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase

But I am missing something on the first page if you click on the simple link you get back "Hello World" in green.

So I looked in the JSP page and I found this code:

```
<ul>
            <li>
                <a id="simpleLink" class="textLink" href="<c:url value="/simple" />">GET /simple</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="simpleRevisited" class="textLink" href="<c:url value="/simple/revisited" />">GET /simple/revisited</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Where does the call to the contoller but I dont see how the JSP page knows where to put the "Hello World" in green.

I then reviewed the control and I found:

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {

    @RequestMapping("/simple")
    public @ResponseBody String simple() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }

}
```

Which sents the "Hello World" out to the JSP but how does the JSP know where to put it?  I dont see any tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the magic is happening in the jQuery at the bottom of the [JSP code](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp). This is a bit complicated for a Hello World tutorial, but that's besides the point.

On click of a link, request the the data from the server using AJAX:

```
$("a.textLink").click(function(){
    var link = $(this);
    $.ajax({ url: link.attr("href"), dataType: "text", success: function(text) { MvcUtil.showSuccessResponse(text, link); }, error: function(xhr) { MvcUtil.showErrorResponse(xhr.responseText, link); }});
    return false;
});
```

Eventually, following through the JavaScript methods, you reach this bit of code which sets up a response element and displays the *Hello World* message on the page.

```
MvcUtil.showResponse = function(type, text, element) {
    var responseElementId = element.attr("id") + "Response";
    var responseElement = $("#" + responseElementId);
    if (responseElement.length == 0) {
        responseElement = $('<span id="' + responseElementId + '" class="' + type + '" style="display:none">' + text + '</span>').insertAfter(element);
    } else {
        responseElement.replaceWith('<span id="' + responseElementId + '" class="' + type + '" style="display:none">' + text + '</span>');
    responseElement = $("#" + responseElementId);
    }
    responseElement.fadeIn("slow");
};
```